# directories with two one dot (.) entries

Tags: linux, ext3, directory, rm, files

I'm trying to clean up my lost and found, and I've managed to remove most things, but I'm left with "almost" empty directories, like:

```
lost+found/#14042862:
total 1324
dr---wx---  2 76040 43010    4096 2011-04-29 07:56 .
dr---wx---  2 76040 43010    4096 2011-04-29 07:56 .
drwx------ 18 root  root  1187840 2011-04-29 07:56 ..
```

- How did I get directories with duplicate entries?
- Is it safe to unlink the directory when rm complains it's not empty?
- WTF???

Comment: Is that really a duplicate `.` entry? Run `ls -libq` to see the inode numbers and expose nonprintable characters. But if you have files in `lost+found`, your filesystem's probably taken some damage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's really a duplicate.  And a force delete may have worked, but an fsck was the proper fix.  Basically, I ran fsck, and it saw some bytes it thought was a directory, so it just put a directory entry for it in the lost+found.  Running fsck again actually checked the contents of the directory, found the duplicate, and removed it.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend checking the inode listing of the directory.  It's possible that they really aren't the same file.

```
ls -al -i
```

You might also check to see if one of the directories has a hidden (or non-printable) character with:

```
ls -al -Q
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you did that, but I'd force delete it and run fsck asap.